# Mayavi dialog with black background

Tags: python, wxpython, vtk, mayavi

I am getting exactly the same problems as reported by Tom Foutz at [Importing mayavi from python creates pop-up with black background on UI (Mavericks/Canopy)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22393103/importing-mayavi-from-python-creates-pop-up-with-black-background-on-ui-maveric).

However I am using Mayavi from the mayavi.mlab module which I am calling from a vanilla python 2.7.9 installation (GCC 4.2.1 build) running in OS X Yosemite. I have wxPython 3.0.2.0, mayavi/tvtk 4.4.2 and vtk 6.2 installed.

I have added "export ETS_TOOLKIT=qt4" to the environment without any success.

I also experience the same problem when calling a dialog box with the following script:

```
from tvtk.api import tvtk
p = tvtk.Property()
p.configure_traits()
```

In this circumstance I have the option to change the view type to "Advanced".  On doing so, I am advised that

> 12:34:23: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile.

I would be grateful for any advice on how to fix this. Thanks.